# Help With UV Maps?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

Well I am working with vectors right now and I kinda ran into a problem with textures. I was going to export the UV map so I could paste the texture over and have it properly put in but . . .
[image: No UV option in the image editor]

There doesn't seem to be a UV option in the image editor. :L
Anyone know how to fix or if I'm doing something wrong? I'm probably doing something wrong.

Comment: might be a stupid question but have you unwrapped it?

Comment: You can't unwrap bezier curve objects. If it is just a simple image applied to the bounds use *Generated* texture coordinates, otherwise convert (a copy) to mesh and unwrap.

Comment: Oh, well I don't know how to use generated texture coordinates.